# Querying AWS Cloudwatch Log Group Subscriptions Using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Within AWS CloudWatch it is possible to add [`Subscriptions` to a `Log group`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) so that logs within the group can flow to Kinesis, Firehose, etc.  These subscriptions can be viewed in the console:

[image]

**How can the 'Subscriptions' values be queried using boto3?**

I have tried the following

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('logs', region_name='us-east-1')
client.describe_log_groups()
```

But that only returns the following attributes (note: specific values have been redacted):

```
{'logGroups': [{'logGroupName': '<myGroupNameValue>',   
   'creationTime': <myCreationTimeValue>,    'metricFilterCount': 0,
   'arn': '<myArnValue>', 
   'storedBytes': <myStoredBytesValue>},
   ...]}
```

The returned json does not include a 'subscriptions' key/value pair.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `describe_subscription_filters` API. 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_subscription_filters

Does that help you?